# Apache 2.4 HTTPS Redirect works after first use

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, gitlab

I use the official Gitlab Apache 2.4 template for my gitlab installation. When accessing git.example.com the first time, I get a timeout. After visiting https://git.example.com the redirect works even when accessing git.example.com whats going wrong there?

here is the template:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName git.example.com
  ServerSignature Off

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
  SSLHonorCipherOrder on
  SSLCipherSuite "ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS"
  Header add Strict-Transport-Security: "max-age=15768000;includeSubdomains"
  SSLCompression Off
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl.crt/YOUR_SERVER_FQDN.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl.key/YOUR_SERVER_FQDN.key
  SSLCACertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl.crt/your-ca.crt

  ServerName YOUR_SERVER_FQDN
  ServerSignature Off

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

  <Location />

    Require all granted    
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8181
    ProxyPassReverse http://git.example.com/
  </Location>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploads/.*
  RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8181%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,NE]

  RequestHeader set X_FORWARDED_PROTO 'https'
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Ssl on
  DocumentRoot /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: what's the purpose of your `Location` directive? Directive, not the text within.

Comment: Actually I don't know. As I just used the provided template and changed it to my needs.

Comment: if you remove `<Location />` and `</Location>`, does it change anything?

Comment: Is `ServerName YOUR_SERVER_FQDN` scrubbed? Or did you forget to complete that?